# pipe line with non-deterministic output

Tags: shell-script, awk, io-redirection, concurrency

I have happened upon a command that sometimes works and sometimes does not, even when executed multiple times in rapid succession in a `bash` shell (I have not tested the behavior in other shells). The problem has been localized to the reading of a variable in the `BEGIN` block of an `awk` statement at the end of the pipe line. During some executions, the variable is correctly read in the `BEGIN` block and during other executions, the operation fails. Supposing this aberrant behavior can be reproduced by others (and is not a consequence of some problem with my system), can its inconsistency be explained?

Take as input the following file called `tmp`:

```
cat > tmp <<EOF
a   a
b   *
aa  a
aaa a
aa  a
a   a
c   *
aaa a
aaaa    a
d   *
aaa a
a   a
aaaaa   a
e   *
aaaa    a
aaa a
f   *
aa  a
a   a
g   *
EOF
```

On my system, the pipe line

```
 awk '{if($2!~/\*/) print $1}' tmp | tee >(wc -l | awk '{print $1}' > n.txt) | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1,1nr | awk 'BEGIN{getline n < "n.txt"}{print $1 "\t" $1/n*100 "\t" $2}'
```

will either produce the correct output:

```
4   28.5714 a
4   28.5714 aaa
3   21.4286 aa
2   14.2857 aaaa
1   7.14286 aaaaa
```

or the error message:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

How can a command *possibly* give different output when run twice in succession when no random number generation is involved and no change to the environment is made in the interim?

To demonstrate how absurd the behavior is, consider the output generated by executing the above pipe line ten times consecutively in a loop:

```
for x in {1..10}; do echo "Iteration ${x}"; awk '{if($2!~/\*/) print $1}' tmp | tee >(wc -l | awk '{print $1}' > n.txt) | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1,1nr | awk 'BEGIN{getline n < "n.txt"}{print $1 "\t" $1/n*100 "\t" $2}'; done
Iteration 1
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
Iteration 2
4   28.5714 a
4   28.5714 aaa
3   21.4286 aa
2   14.2857 aaaa
1   7.14286 aaaaa
Iteration 3
4   28.5714 a
4   28.5714 aaa
3   21.4286 aa
2   14.2857 aaaa
1   7.14286 aaaaa
Iteration 4
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
Iteration 5
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
Iteration 6
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
Iteration 7
4   28.5714 a
4   28.5714 aaa
3   21.4286 aa
2   14.2857 aaaa
1   7.14286 aaaaa
Iteration 8
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
Iteration 9
4   28.5714 a
4   28.5714 aaa
3   21.4286 aa
2   14.2857 aaaa
1   7.14286 aaaaa
Iteration 10
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

Note: I have also tried closing the file (awk `close`) after reading the variable, in case the problem relates to the file being left open. However, the inconsistent output remains.

Comment: not sure yet on how to fix this, but I know the error is  b/c this portion: `$1/n*100`, specifically by `n`. If for example, you remove that `n` your script runs fine. This should be related to `n` value read from `n.txt`.

Comment: You're trying to count the occurrences of lines in a file? Like `28.5714 a` occurs 4 times? I think you'd have a lot more luck with `uniq` or `grep -c`. My bad - I see that pipeline is a lot longer than I at first realized - and I mostly have the same question that ^ previous guy did - n? It some kind of formulae related to percentage like 4 times is close to 27% - but there's something else. 2% else. Anyway, I'm sure it can be much simplified and I urge you to try. `sort` - for instance - is *never* a back-pipe friendly process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your redirections have a race condition. This:

```
>(wc -l | awk '{print $1}' > n.txt)
```

runs in parallel with:

```
awk 'BEGIN{getline n < "n.txt"}...'
```

later in the pipeline. Sometimes, `n.txt` is still empty when the `awk` program starts running.

This is (obliquely) documented in the Bash Reference Manual. In a [pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines):

> The output of each command in the pipeline is connected via a pipe to the input of the next command. That is, each command reads the previous command’s output. *This connection is performed before any redirections specified by the command*.

and then:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell

(emphasis added). *All* the processes in the pipeline are started, with their input and output connected together, without waiting for any of the earlier programs to finish or even start doing anything. Before that, [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) with `>(...)` is:

> performed simultaneously with parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.

What that means is that the subprocess running the `wc -l | awk ...` command starts early on, and the redirection empties `n.txt` just before that, but the `awk` process that causes the error is started shortly after. Both of those commands execute in parallel - you'll have several processes going at once here.

**The error occurs when `awk` runs its `BEGIN` block before the `wc` command's output has been written into `n.txt`**. In that case, the `n` variable is empty, and so is zero when used as a number. If the `BEGIN` runs after the file is filled in, everything works.

When that happens depends on the operating system scheduler, and which process gets a slot first, which is essentially random from the user perspective. If the final `awk` gets to run early, or the `wc` pipeline gets scheduled a little later, the file will still be empty when `awk` starts doing its work and the whole thing will break. In all likelihood the processes will run on different cores actually simultaneously, and it's down to which one gets to the point of contention first. The effect you'll get is probably of the command working more often than not, but sometimes failing with the error you post.

---

In general, pipelines are only safe in so far as they're just pipelines - standard output into standard input is fine, but because the processes execute in parallel **it's not reliable to rely on the sequencing of any other communication channels**, like files, or of any part of any one process executing before or after any part of another unless they're locked together by reading standard input.

The workaround here is probably to do all your file writing in advance of needing them: at the end of a line, it's guaranteed that an entire pipeline and all of its redirections have completed before the next command runs. This command will never be reliable, but if you really do need it to work in this sort of a structure you can insert a delay (`sleep`) or loop until `n.txt` is non-empty before running the final `awk` command to increase the chances of things working how you want.

Comment: Thanks for a truly exceptional explanation. I was laboring under a flawed understanding of pipelines, which I erroneously perceived to operate in a completely serial fashion. It's true that the `tee` statement produces parallel processes, so even though I wrote the process for variable definition first, there is no reason to expect that it will begin or finish first. Also, I had no idea that the pipes were constructed at the outset, and instead naïvely believed that each pipe was constructed after completion of the preceding process. There is no fundamental reason that I need to employ the ...

Comment: strategy in the example. I was merely trying to condense the workflow into a "one-liner" more for the concision of such a formulation than anything else. Initially, I wanted to avoid writing temporary files as well and tried to pipe the output of the `>(...)` process substitution to a `read` statement to subsequently pass the variable as an argument to the later `awk` script, only to discover that `read` cannot be used in this process because a child process, the state of the `>(...)` construct, has not the ability to alter the environment of its parent process.

Answer (score 5):

`pipe` expression in `process substitution` causes a race condition in `bash` and `ksh`, `zsh` doesn't.

The main problem here is that `zsh` waits, `bash` doesn't.

You can see more details [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.shell/1ky9m5CQQlY).

A quick fixed, adding `sleep 1` in your `awk` to make `n.txt` always available:

```
awk 'BEGIN{system("sleep 1");getline n < "n.txt"};{print $1 "\t" $1/n*100 "\t" $2}'
```

Comment: Thanks for linking to an interesting discussion. I am inclined to favor the `zsh` model of synchronizing the processes. It's interesting that the first process after the `tee` will finish first if a `sleep` is imposed, but finish either first or second (pseudo-randomly) if not.

Answer (score 3):

The race condition is already identified. But if you'd like an easier solution, you don't need a separate `wc` to count the records, `awk` can do it:

```
awk '{if($2!~/\*/){print $1;++n}END{print n >"n.txt"}' tmp | sort | uniq -c ...
```

Beyond that, `awk` can count like `sort|uniq -c` as long as the values fit in memory, and also do the x/n calculation, but may output in "random" order; also using match/action is tidier:

```
awk '$2!~/\*/{++k[$1];++n} END{for(i in k){print k[i]"\t"k[i]/n*100"\t"i}}' tmp | sort -k1nr
```

Or in recent *GNU* `awk` you can set `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc"` so the `for` uses the correct order and you don't need the `sort`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. I'll use that. Particularly when a process is quite compute- or IO-intensive (my actual data files are gigabytes), obviating the need for process re-execution (saving a result from the first execution in a variable or temporary file to be read and used during the second execution) is desirable. Thanks for mentioning the preferred `match`/`action` formulation as well. I'm aware of it, but rarely make use of it, as resorting to the `if` statement has become a pernicious habit of mine.